# Docker container not printing logs not location specified in log4j2.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, logging, log4j2

I have configured a Docker Image for my Spring boot application. I have also configured logs using log4j.xml. But, on running the docker image, the logs are getting printed neither in the docker logs nor on the location specified in log4j.xml.

**Below is my Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD <relative path to jar>/jar-name.jar jar-name.jar
ADD <relative path to property file>/application.properties /app/application.properties
ADD <relative path to log4j file>/log4j2-8081.xml /logs/log4j2-8081.xml
ENV JAVA_OPTS="8080"
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dapp.home=classpath:file:/app/", "- 
Dlog4j.configurationFile=classpath:file:/logs/log4j2-8081.xml", "-jar", "jar-name.jar"]
```

I need to pass the log4j.xml file path during the execution of the docker run command.
Thanks in advance

**Docker Run Command**:-

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 -e JAVA_OPTS=-Dserver.port=8081 rdsstg
```

Comment: What is your log path directory in log4j? You will be required to create the directory in Docker and try it again.

Also when you run spring application, the what is the log configuration - to print on console or file. If file, the directory should exist

Comment: I want to create logs outside the container. In the location /log of the system.

Answer (score 0):

So per your query you are saying the logs aren't getting printed per the log4j config in application code and in your docker container, kindly correct my inference. Thanks.

Now per your comment,

> I want to create logs outside the container. In the location /log of the system.

The answer is to use volumes, where-in the path of host machine and docker container is provided. The bare minimal usage is to use `-v option` See below. For deep dive please refer [Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for more details.

`docker run -p 8081:8081 -e JAVA_OPTS=-Dserver.port=8081 -v /host_machine/log:/container/var/app/log rdsstg`

**BUT**, you do need to understand in order for your docker container to direct log files(or any files per say) on host machine, those files should be generated in container i.e app logging should be working in container. This is your **#1**

Let me know if above make sense.

- On a side note

  for `-e` usage, I would recommend to use the `--env-file` option so that you can keep multiple env variables in one file instead of passing multiple `-e`.

It would have been difficult to explain in comments section.